Transplanting plants to different pots without disturbing the roots at all?
So I'm in a bit of an interesting scenario, I enjoy growing obscure US native plants and have been starting a few indoors for the next growing season and they've mostly been doing well. I group I really enjoy are the US native Astragalus species, which come with a lot of challenges. What really makes them difficult is that they are very taproot-oriented, and create sensitive root hairs on the bottoms of said taproots, that are easy to break. This breakage seemingly results in problems for the plant later on, so I'd like some input into ways of transplanting these plants to new pots without disturbing the roots whatsoever.
I have one method in mind, which is cutting a decent sized hole below where the roots are coming down, and then just place them in the new pot and let the roots enter naturally. This is my only plan so far, so any other ideas are much appreciated!

Hi Dave, welcome to the site!  Glad to see some Astragalus love, I wish I knew more about your obscure natives.  Could you please tell us what the plants are in now that you are transplanting out of, and how far along the plants are when you transplant them for the first and last times?

The plants are currently in these 4 or 5 inch diameter plastic containers, with 5 inches of depth give or take. I can't exactly pinpoint when I will transplant them, but I imagine it is soon because I can start seeing their small taproot get close to the bottom of the container, and they are getting their first sets of true leaves developed. I was thinking of transplanting them into one of those 12 inch long sapling pots you may see at nurseries sometimes, but I'm not sure yet.

Probably does not help with your existing plants, but I'm grappling with a slightly analogous problem, and next season I'm going to try use pots made of coir or similar material that will break down (possibly putting those pots in plastic pots for support) and then just planting those.

Astragalogia made famous DC (the first well known botanist named De Candolle), I hope you get so far! -- Depending on the soil, if you water the pot and cut the plastic, you should have compact soil and few damages to roots. For more detailes answers you may need to google for some research on how to growth Astragalus: sometime some researches publish them (and because everybody loves A. I think you may find some): usually there are some hints on what it is important and what not (else very boring recipes).

Soil cubes (which are not pots, but serve the function, somewhat) are the only method I know of with "zero transplant shock" though peat pots or other porous natural materials that break down could also work. Some of the peat pots on the market don't seem to break down well enough to work as expected for letting roots grow through them, so testing may be called for.
